# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u30db' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: unicode, python-3.6

I want to get meta info of audio files by TinyTag. An example of the file name with a relative path is './_ホ_ケモンGO_レイト_ハ_トル_モンシ_ャラ_カイロス軍団て_撃破_.m4a'. I am working in a Linux Python3.6 environment and using Jupyter notebook.

Using:

```
tag = TinyTag.get(fname)
```

I get:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u30db' in
>   position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

I tried:

```
tag = TinyTag.get(fname.encode('U8'))
```

and get:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

How can I make this work? thanks

Comment: Unicode names in Python 3 should work.  Is your Linux environment correctly configured?  See https://perlgeek.de/en/article/set-up-a-clean-utf8-environment.

Comment: Yes, I have already export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 on linux, thanks